# Why is canvas.create_rectangle not working when used in tkinter.after()

Tags: python, tkinter, overlay

I am trying to display an overlay using the `overlay` package which is built on top of `tkinter`. When I run this process, the output is correct and I see the overlay displays the correct fill colors (i.e. 3 rectangles are green, red, blue)

```
_overlay = Overlay(
  window.data["kCGWindowBounds"]["X"],
  window.data["kCGWindowBounds"]["Y"]
)

screen = Screen(
  window.data["kCGWindowBounds"]["X"], 
  window.data["kCGWindowBounds"]["Y"], 
  window.data["kCGWindowBounds"]["Height"], 
  window.data["kCGWindowBounds"]["Width"]
)

screen.capture()

pattern = Pattern()
pattern.convertImageToRGB()

pixelOne = pattern.getColorOnePixel()
pixelTwo = pattern.getColorTwoPixel()

_overlay.displayPattern(pixelOne, pixelTwo)

overlay.Window.launch()

...

def displayPattern(self, pixelOne, pixelTwo):
  colors = COLOR_ONE_PIXEL_MAP.get(pixelOne, "Undefined") + COLOR_TWO_PIXEL_MAP.get(pixelTwo, "Undefined")

  pattern = COLOR_PATTERN_MAP.get(colors, "Undefined")

  canvas = tk.Canvas(
    self.window.root,
    width=162,
    height=12,
    bd=0,
    highlightthickness=0
  )

  canvas.pack(
    padx=0,
    pady=0
  )

  if pattern != "Undefined":
    print(pattern)

    canvas.create_rectangle(-1, -1, 54, 12, fill=COLOR_FILL_MAP.get(pattern[:2]), outline=COLOR_FILL_MAP.get(pattern[:2]))
    canvas.create_rectangle(54, -1, 108, 12, fill=COLOR_FILL_MAP.get(pattern[3] + pattern[4]), outline=COLOR_FILL_MAP.get(pattern[3] + pattern[4]))
    canvas.create_rectangle(108, -1, 162, 12, fill=COLOR_FILL_MAP.get(pattern[6] + pattern[7]), outline=COLOR_FILL_MAP.get(pattern[6] + pattern[7]))

    self.window.root.update()
```

Now I need to continue to run this process so that when information on the window that the program is using updates, this function gets run again. So I update this logic to this:

```
overlay.Window.after(
  500, 
  proceed, 
  window.data["kCGWindowBounds"]["X"], 
  window.data["kCGWindowBounds"]["Y"], 
  window.data["kCGWindowBounds"]["Height"], 
  window.data["kCGWindowBounds"]["Width"]
)

overlay.Window.launch()

...

def proceed(x, y, height, width):
  while True:
    screen = Screen(
      x,
      y,
      height,
      width
    )

    screen.capture()

    pattern = Pattern()
    pattern.convertImageToRGB()

    pixelOne = pattern.getColorOnePixel()
    pixelTwo = pattern.getColorTwoPixel()

    _overlay.displayPattern(pixelOne, pixelTwo)

    time.sleep(.5)
```

I'm seeing the correct output in the print() (i.e. GG RR BB green red blue), but those fill colors are no longer being applied to the canvas.create_rectangle method. Is there something I'm missing with the after() process and packing tkinter canvas elements?

Comment: I see `while True` - so you run endless loop and this may block `root.mainloop()` so it can't update/redraw elements in window. It may need to use `root.update()` to force `mainloop` to update elements in window. OR you should use `after(500, process, ...)` instead of `time.sleep()` and `while True`

Comment: if you have to use `while` then you need `root.update()` inside this loop so `mainloop` will have time to update/redraw elements in draw. `tkinter` (like many GUIs) doesn't draws/updates elements in window at once but `mainloop` waits for end of you function  to redraw/update all elements in one moment and this way it has less work and window doesn't blink.

Comment: That makes sense. I tried to add self.window.root.update() at the end of the displayPattern method. It would update once and then wouldn't update again (slight progress). I attempted to keep the `while True` and just add the after(...) function again, but that didnt work either

Comment: did you run in console to see if you get any error message? Maybe there is some problem which block code.

Comment: I am running via console. I'm not getting any errors, and the log is correctly updating. If i click around the output changes colors (expected), but the rectangles don't get drawn still

Comment: I can't run your code so I can't help more.

Comment: It's difficult to reproduce as it relies on a 3rd party game window which I don't expected for you to download, but I could link you to the repository as its public

Comment: put all information in question - it will be better visible and maybe someone else will help you.

Answer (score 1):

`tkinter` (like other GUIs) doesn't draw/update elements at once but it waits for end of your function to redraw/update all elements in one moment - this way it has less work and window doesn't blink.

Problem is that your function runs `while True` so it never ends.

You may use `root.update()` inside loop to force `tkinter` to redraw elements

```
def proceed(x, y, height, width):
  while True:
    screen = Screen(
      x,
      y,
      height,
      width
    )

    screen.capture()

    pattern = Pattern()
    pattern.convertImageToRGB()

    pixelOne = pattern.getColorOnePixel()
    pixelTwo = pattern.getColorTwoPixel()

    _overlay.displayPattern(pixelOne, pixelTwo)

    overlay.Window.update()   # <--- force tkinter to redraw/update window

    time.sleep(.5)
```

OR you can use `after(500, process, ...)` instead of `while True` and `time.sleep()`

```
def proceed(x, y, height, width):

    screen = Screen(
      x,
      y,
      height,
      width
    )

    screen.capture()

    pattern = Pattern()
    pattern.convertImageToRGB()

    pixelOne = pattern.getColorOnePixel()
    pixelTwo = pattern.getColorTwoPixel()

    _overlay.displayPattern(pixelOne, pixelTwo)

    overlay.Window.after(500, process, x, y, height, width)  # <--- run again after 500ms
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Here's a link to the repo https://github.com/Rynebenson/YPPSFPatternTool I'm not sure if you'll be able to run it as it will only work on MacOS and without the 3rd party application running it will just say "Looking for window..."

Comment: I will work on a minimal reproducible example in the meanwhile